# Should this question about the Assassin's Creed novelization be downvoted?

Tags: discussion

Recently, [someone asked a question about the Assassin's Creed novelizations](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/2064/111) that was heavily downvoted.

I'm curious why this question was downvoted, and if people think that it's a good question for the site. Are the downvotes because people don't want questions about Assassin's Creed novelizations on this site, or are the downvotes because of another reason? How can the question be improved?

Comment: I'll state here, just in case, that [literary works and their adaptations are on-topic](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/56/should-we-accept-questions-asking-to-compare-a-book-and-its-adaptation). It has never been stated that the _reverse_ should be off-topic; still, maybe someone will want to write up an answer there.

Answer (score 6):

I asked that question, and let me make my case for it.

The *Assassin's Creed* novels are, well, novelizations, and accordingly, there are constraints on the author:

- The IP owners may have their own desires and ideas about how the series would evolve, which the author might have to respect. Indeed, an unlikely hypothesis is that Ubisoft want the modern-day events to be combined in a single novel.
- The fans may have an expectation that the novels will be faithful to the original, and indeed expand upon it.
- The author may not have control over how the series will evolve, so every change made would have to be made keeping in mind the need to compound that change in the future.

Any point of difference in the novels is not *merely* the will of the author.

In fact, differences like this are things I would expect one or more of the following to comment on:

- the IP owners
- the author,
- other authors and (and those involved in creating non-literature works) in the same universe - for example:

  - the movie novelization was written by another author, and it certainly has modern-day events.
  - a separate series is expected to contain modern-day events as well.

  Authors of either might have communicated with Bowden and discussed this.

Now it's certainly possible that nobody has commented on this *yet*. But this is a significant change and it must certainly have been discussed, if behind closed doors. We may never know, but that is no reason why the question shouldn't be asked.