# Why did these questions receive downvotes?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, specific-question

I have several questions related to song lyrics:

- [Why does "Nighttime Birds" associate night with warmth?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3556/why-does-nighttime-birds-associate-night-with-warmth)
- [Are there two separate narrators in "On Most Surfaces" by The Gathering?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3503/are-there-two-separate-narrators-in-on-most-surfaces-by-the-gathering)
- [Why are "Heaven" and "Las Vegas" contrasted in "Heaven or Las Vegas"?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/why-are-heaven-and-las-vegas-contrasted-in-heaven-or-las-vegas)
- [Why is "On Most Surfaces" titled the way that it is given that only one surface appears in the song itself?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/3504/why-is-on-most-surfaces-titled-the-way-that-it-is-given-that-only-one-surface)

All have received a mix of upvotes and downvotes. The downvoters offered no explanation whatsoever for why they downvoted. I'm slightly baffled as to why, because they seem like reasonable questions to me. It would've been better if the downvotes themselves would've explained, but I am curious: why might people have downvoted these? Is there actually a problem with the quality of these questions? If so, how can they be improved?

Comment: I'll be interested to see if you get any answers, I almost posted a comment on your 'Nighttime Birds' question to ask why it was downvoted.

Comment: I *suspect* there may be someone who simply thinks [tag:song-lyrics] should be off-topic and downvotes all such questions on principle (same for [tag:story-identification]), but of course I can't prove anything.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I suspected the same thing - I was hoping that that wasn't the case, though, especially given that the current community consensus is that those questions are on topic - it seems like a bad reason to downvote.

Comment: @yannis I completely disagree. "Toxic" seems like a significant exaggeration *at best*, especially given that the people who actually downvoted didn't bother to give an explanation themselves. IMHO, that's the *actual* toxic behavior here, especially for a site that's still in Beta and is still building consensus around what constitutes a "reasonable" question on the site.

Comment: @yannis I disagree - people should only downvote for valid reasons. The **only** valid reason to downvote is that the question doesn't meet the quality standards set by the community, **not** the fact that you happen to dislike the question by whatever arbitrary criteria you set. The tooltip for downvotes says "this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." There's no room for "I happen to dislike this question because it doesn't meet my personal standards."

Comment: @yannis My point isn't that my definition is better than yours, it's that the community's definition is what we should go by when downvoting. I can't let my personal opinion trump a community consensus to the contrary.

Comment: @yannis Not sure why you're calling *me* out specifically when at least three other people, [including a site mod](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/607/17), have posted "why was this downvoted" questions on meta and I *haven't* (in fact I tend to be against such questions for much the same reason as you).